# Python перестал работать в командной строке

Tags: python

Питон не хотел работать в командной строке, на любую команду просто отвечает Python и ничего не делает. Запускал в cmd и в командной строке в vscode. До этого все нормально всегда работало, при установке добавлял в PATH, только сейчас перестало работать
[image: Проблема]

Comment: Что-то у вас не то наверное вместо питона запускается. Может бат-файл у вас там есть с таким именем или ещё что?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте команду `py`

```
py --version
py main.py
py -m venv env
```

и тд

Если владеете знаниями в windows, можете настроить переменные среды